# Rails Polymorphic Assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, nested-attributes

I've had success creating dependent polymorphic associations using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but now I would like to assign an already existing polymorph.  I'm getting the error:

```
undefined method `id' for {"id"=>"4"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :company_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :address do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.collection_select :id, Address.all, :id, :description, {:prompt => "-Select Address"} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

The resulting params hash is:

```
"company"=>{"company_name"=>"myCompanyName", "address"=>{"id"=>"4"}}
```

Which looks reasonable to me.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change `f.fields_for :address do |f|` to `f.fields_for :address do |d|` and `f.collection_select` to `d.collection_select` if it isn't mistype

```
<%= form_for @company do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :company_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :address do |d| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= d.collection_select :id, Address.all, :id, :description, {:prompt => "-Select Address"} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion.  Same error.  What is my params hash supposed to look like in this case?

Comment: Block parameters are always local to the block, so the form builder object `f` in the `fields_for` is not the same as in the outer `form_for`, which can be seen by inspecting `f.object_id`. Though it is wise to use a different name to make it easier to read.

Comment: check if `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` presents in `Company` model

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` to `Person` and `Company`, which produces a params hash like this:

```
{"company"=>{"company_name"=>"myCompanyName", "address_attributes"=>{"id"=>"4"}}}
```